# how to export a file to sharepoint (office 365) using ssis sql agent job?

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

i tried to copy the file using copy/xcopy from batch file, but it is not working.
then i downloaded ssis integration tool kit from (http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-sharepoint/download ) and tried to create a sharepoint connection manger to send the file using file system task, but getting error as unknown namespace type for user in sharepoint connection manager while creating connection manager.

is there any other way to send the files to sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for downloading our software.

It looks like you were not able to build the connection with SharePoint. Can you post the full error message so that we can better assist you?

Once you have created the SharePoint connection manager, it would be fairly easy to upload files to SharePoint using the **Premium File Transfer Task** which comes with our SharePoint Toolkit.

You can also reach out to us through our official support channel if you have any further questions.

Best regards,
KingswaySoft Support

Comment: Error message : TITLE: SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft SharePoint (v5.0.0.826)
------------------------------

System.Exception: Unknown namespace type for user 'xxxx.gollapudi': Unknown (SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft SharePoint, v5.0.0.826 - devenv, v10.0.40219.1)



------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------

Comment: Hi Yogi, we believe we had talked yesterday :). You would need to provide the same username as the one when you use to login through the SharePoint web UI. Then, you should be able to build the connection with SharePoint. Thank you for choosing KingswaySoft, please let us know if you have any further questions. Best regards.